# Java - how to connect classes, methods, constructors?

Tags: java, class, object, connection

I have a game in Processing and there are two classes - main and player. I'm thinking the main class should have the setup and menu, and the player class have the controls, collision, movement etc.

I need help figuring out how to connect the two classes so the game can run. In the main class some variables and methods are not defined so I know I'm not referencing or calling them right.
I'm fairly new to classes and methods so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Main class:

```
//used for setup
//makes program run
//diff currents? play/instr/dead/replay
PFont title, main, dead;
PImage candy, lollipop, cottonCandy;
PImage badApple, bananaPeel, pepper;
PImage panda, heart, bkgrd;
PImage [] goodCandy = new PImage [3];
PImage [] badFood = new PImage [3];
PrintWriter highScore;

String current="menu";
int menuBut1x, menuBut1y;
int menuBut2x, menuBut2y;
int menuBut3x, menuBut3y;
int backButx, backButy;

void setup() {
  size(1200,700);
  frameRate(30);
  title = loadFont("Gabriola-150.vlw");
  textFont(title);
  main = loadFont("SegoeUI-Light-60.vlw");
  textFont(main);
  dead = loadFont("Stencil-200.vlw");
  textFont(dead);

  highScore = createWriter("HighScore.txt");

  menuBut1x = width/3-70;
  menuBut1y = height/2-100;
  menuBut2x = width/3-70;
  menuBut2y = height/2+40;
  menuBut3x = width/3-70;
  menuBut3y = height/2+180;
  backButx = 1030;
  backButy = 10;
  candy = loadImage("goodCandy0.png");
  cottonCandy = loadImage("goodCandy1.png");
  lollipop = loadImage("goodCandy2.png");
  badApple = loadImage("badFood0.png");
  bananaPeel = loadImage("badFood1.png");
  pepper = loadImage("badFood2.png");
  panda = loadImage("panda.png");
  heart = loadImage("heart.png");
  bkgrd = loadImage("floatClouds.jpg");

  for (int i=0; i<goodCandy.length; i++) {
  goodCandy[i] = loadImage("goodCandy" + i + ".png"); //loading goodCandy imgs via array
}
  for (int i=0; i<badFood.length; i++) {
  badFood[i] = loadImage("badFood" + i + ".png"); //loading badFood imgs via array
}
}


public void menu (){
  background(#bfefff);
  fill(255);
  rect(menuBut1x, menuBut1y, 520, 100); //first button
  rect(menuBut2x, menuBut2y, 520, 100); //second button
  rect(menuBut3x, menuBut3y, 520, 100); //third button
  textSize(100);
  fill(#000000);
  textFont(title);
  text("Candy Dash!", 300, 180);
  textSize(200);
  fill(#000000);
  textFont(main);
  text("PLAY", 530, 320);
  textSize(65);
  fill(#000000);
  textFont(main);
  text("INSTRUCTIONS", 400, 465);
  textSize(65);
  fill(#000000);
  textFont(main);
  text("HIGH SCORES", 415, 600);

  if (current=="menu") {
    //background(#F0D5E2); DON'T HAVE BACKGROUND COLOUR HERE OR WILL COVER EVERYTHING - BKGRD TOP OF VOID DRAW
    if (mouseX >= menuBut1x && mouseX <= menuBut1x+520 && mouseY >= menuBut1y && mouseY <= menuBut1y+100 && mousePressed) {
          current="play";   //clicked play button     
  }
  if (mouseX >= menuBut2x && mouseX <= menuBut2x+520 && mouseY >= menuBut2y && mouseY <= menuBut2y+100 && mousePressed) {
          current="instructions";   //clicked instructions button     
  }
  if (mouseX >= menuBut3x && mouseX <= menuBut3x+520 && mouseY >= menuBut3y && mouseY <= menuBut3y+100 && mousePressed) {
          current="high scores";   //clicked high scores button     
  }
  pandaX = 550; //resets the panda to starting position 
  pandaY = 580; //RESET EVERYTHING WHEN EXIT
  points = 0;
  }

  if (current=="instructions") {
    background(#e8f0f7);
    textSize(80);
    text("INSTRUCTIONS", 360, 140);
    textSize(35);
    text("Use the arrow keys to move left and right.", 100,240);
    text("Your goal is to collect all the yummy candies, and avoid the bad foods!", 100, 300);
    text("Watch out! Touch a bad food and YOU ARE DEAD!", 100, 360);
    fill(#F0FFF0); //back button
    rect(backButx, backButy, 160, 100); //back button
    textSize(50); 
    fill(#000000);
    text("MENU", 1040, 75);
    textSize(35); 
    fill(#000000);
    text("COLLECT THESE:", 180, 450);
    image(candy, 80, 480, 120, 80);
    image(lollipop, 220, 480, 100, 170);
    image(cottonCandy, 350, 480, 100, 180);
    text("AVOID THESE:", 800, 450);
    image(badApple, 720, 480, 100, 140);
    image(bananaPeel, 830, 480, 180, 170);
    image(pepper, 1030, 470, 100, 170);

    if (mouseX >= backButx && mouseX <= backButx+160 && mouseY >= backButy && mouseY <= backButy+100 && mousePressed) {
          current="menu";   //clicked menu button     
  }
  }

  if (current=="high scores") {
    background(#e8f0f7);
    fill(#F0FFF0);
    rect(backButx, backButy, 160, 100); //back button
    textSize(50);
    fill(#000000);
    text("MENU", 1040, 75);
    textSize(100);
    text("HIGH SCORE: " + points, 300, height/2);

    if (mouseX >= backButx && mouseX <= backButx+160 && mouseY >= backButy && mouseY <= backButy+100 && mousePressed) {
          current="menu";   //clicked menu button      
  }
  }

    if (current=="play") {
    image(bkgrd, 0, 0, 1200, 700);
    //background(#cfe1e1);
    fill(#F0FFF0);
    rect(backButx, backButy, 160, 100); //back button
    textSize(50);
    fill(#000000);
    text("MENU", 1040, 75);

    candyFall(); //calling methods
    touchCandy();
    newCandy();
    badFoodFall();

    if (mouseX >= backButx && mouseX <= backButx+160 && mouseY >= backButy && mouseY <= backButy+100 && mousePressed) {
          current="menu";   //clicked menu button  
  }
  }
  if (current=="gameOver") {
    background(#7B0B1F);
    textFont(dead);
    textSize(150);
    text("YOU ARE DEAD", 70, height/2);

    textFont(main);
    fill(#fbfbfb);
    rect(200, 500, 300, 150); //replay button
    textSize(80);
    fill(#000000);
    noStroke();
    text("REPLAY", 220, 600);

    fill(#fbfbfb);
    rect(700, 500, 300, 150); //menu button
    textSize(80);
    fill(#000000);
    noStroke();
    text("MENU", 745, 600);
    highScore.println("High Score: " + points); // Write the points to the file

    points=0; //reset points to 0 when dead
    pandaX = 550; //resets pandaX when dead
    pandaY = 580; //resets pandaY when dead

  if (mouseX >= 200 && mouseX <= 200+300 && mouseY >= 500 && mouseY <= 500+150 && mousePressed) {
          current="play";   //clicked replay
  }
  if (mouseX >= 700 && mouseX <= 700+300 && mouseY >= 500 && mouseY <= 500+150 && mousePressed) {
          current="menu";   //clicked menu button 
  }
}
  }
```

Player class:

```
//controls movement of panda, collision w/ falling objects, etc -- all in different methods

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Player implements Serializable {

  public int pandaX, pandaY, pandaW, pandaH;
  public int candyY, candyX, candyW, candyH;
  public int randCandyW, randCandyH, badAppleX, randY, lolliY;
  public int rand, randX, randX2, lolliX;
  public int points;
  public int candySpeed, foodSpeed;
  public int yDirCandy, yDirFood;

  //constructor of class, where default values are assigned (coordinates, points, etc)
  public Player(){
   //setting up default coordinates
   pandaX = 550;
   pandaY = 580;
   pandaW = 80;
   pandaH = 112;
   points = 0;

   candySpeed = 10;
   foodSpeed = 5;
   yDirCandy = 1;
   yDirFood = 1;
   candyY = 10;
   candyX = 200;
   candyW = 187;
   candyH = 121;
   randCandyW = 100;
   randCandyH = 100;
   badAppleX = 700;

   randY = -200;
   lolliY = -600;

   rand = (int) (2*Math.random()) +1;
   randX = (int) (1100*Math.random())+20; 
   randX2 = (int) (1100*Math.random())+20; 
   lolliX = (int) (1100*Math.random())+20;

  }
  public int GetPoints(){ //just test
    return points;
  }

  public void candyFall() {
  image(panda, pandaX, pandaY, pandaW, pandaH);
  fill(#000000);
  text("Points: " + points, 20, 70);
  touchCandy();
  newCandy();

  image(candy, candyX, candyY, candyW, candyH);  //original candy
  candyY = candyY + (candySpeed * yDirCandy);

  image(goodCandy[rand], randX, randY, randCandyW, randCandyH); //rand candy
  randY = randY + (candySpeed * yDirCandy);

  image(lollipop, lolliX, lolliY, randCandyW, randCandyH); //lolli candy
  lolliY = lolliY + (candySpeed * yDirCandy);

highScore.println("High Score: " + points); // Write the points to the file
}

public void badFoodFall(){
  image(badFood[rand], randX2, randY, randCandyW, randCandyH);  //rand food
  randY = randY + (candySpeed * yDirCandy);

  image(badApple, badAppleX, randY, randCandyW, randCandyH);  //rand food
  randY = randY + (candySpeed * yDirFood);
}
public void keyPressed() {
  if (key==CODED) {
    if (keyCode==LEFT) {
      pandaX = pandaX-20; 
    }
    if (keyCode==RIGHT) {
      pandaX = pandaX+20;
    }
   if (pandaX<=5) {
     pandaX=5; //if hit into wall panda won't go off screen
   }
   if (pandaX>=1120) {
     pandaX=1120;
   }
   highScore.flush(); // Writes the remaining data to the file
   highScore.close(); // Finishes the file
  }

}

public void touchCandy() {
  if (  (pandaX + pandaW > candyX && //original candy
        pandaX < candyX + candyW &&
        pandaY + pandaH > candyY &&
        pandaY < candyY + candyH) ||
        (pandaX + pandaW > randX && //rand candy
        pandaX < randX + randCandyW &&
        pandaY + pandaH > randY &&
        pandaY < randY + randCandyH) ||
        (pandaX + pandaW > lolliX && //lollipop
        pandaX < lolliX + randCandyW &&
        pandaY + pandaH > lolliY &&
        pandaY < lolliY + randCandyH)
        )
        {
          textSize(60);
          text("YUM! You get points!", 370, 300);
          points = points + 1; //if panda touches candy, get points!
          image(heart, pandaX+20, pandaY-50, 50, 50);
        }
  if ((pandaX + pandaW > randX2 && //rand food
        pandaX < randX2 + randCandyW &&
        pandaY + pandaH > randY &&
        pandaY < randY + randCandyH) ||
        (pandaX + pandaW > badAppleX && //apple
        pandaX < badAppleX + randCandyW &&
        pandaY + pandaH > randY &&
        pandaY < randY + randCandyH))
        {
          current="gameOver";
        }

}

public void newCandy() {
  if (candyY>=850) {
    candyY=0;  //resetting the original candy to top
  }
  if (lolliY>=850) {
    lolliY=0; //resetting lolli to top
  }
  if (randY>=850) {
    randY=0;
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Any variables that you need to pass to the other class can be passed using parameters.

Comment: And if you want to call methods of one class to another then create an instance of the class object and then call the methods of that class using that object